# Two different OnClick panels in Unity Studio inspector

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have created two projects some time ago.

Probably in two different versions of unity in the beginning.

Now I am opening both in the studio version 5.6.0f3

I am trying to make Buttons onClick events, in the first one its easy, inspector looks normal to me.
[image]

In the second project looks totally different.
[image]

Why is the panel looking differently? Aren't the projects migrated when opening them in new Unity Studio? Can I update both of them somehow to same version? No idea how to add onClick in second project, did not found any tutorial with menu like mine.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no such thing as Unity Studio. Maybe you meant to say "Unity Editor".... Your problem is exactly what [COBO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44398992/3785314) described in is answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the Inspector set to Debug Mode in the second image.

Right click on the Inspector title tab and click Normal instead of Debug.

Comment: Thanks a lot had no idea about this! Just started to play with Unity :)